# My flutter app works on debug but fails on release

Tags: flutter, dart, web

[This is my app during debug mode, everything works perfectly...[And This is my console during debugging, getting a response, just perfect.[However, after building a release...an error occurs.  [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hren.jpg)[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo41H.jpg).[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbxU5.jpg)

below, when building web:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\applications\acl_app> flutter build  web
Building without sound null safety

Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                             62.8s
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\applications\acl_app> flutter clean
Deleting build...                                                  110ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                              67ms
Deleting .packages...                                                1ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       0ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms
Deleting ephemeral...                                               33ms
Deleting ephemeral...                                                1ms
Deleting ephemeral...                                                1ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         0ms
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\applications\acl_app> flutter build web
Running "flutter pub get" in acl_app...                             4.2s

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
```

........

```
flutter run --verbose
```

result

```
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\applications\acl_app> flutter run --verbose
[  +69 ms] executing: [C:\dev\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +53 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] fa5883b78e566877613ad1ccb48dd92075cb5c23
[        ] executing: [C:\dev\flutter/] git tag --points-at fa5883b78e566877613ad1ccb48dd92075cb5c23
[  +41 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at fa5883b78e566877613ad1ccb48dd92075cb5c23
[        ] 2.3.0-16.0.pre
[   +6 ms] executing: [C:\dev\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +29 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/dev
[        ] executing: [C:\dev\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +27 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +106 ms] executing: [C:\dev\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +30 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] dev
[  +85 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +73 ms] executing: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +51 ms] List of devices attached
[  +56 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +11 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +79 ms] Multiple devices found:
[  +20 ms] Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.985]
[  +83 ms] Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77
[        ] Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.37
[   +2 ms] [1]: Windows (windows)
[        ] [2]: Chrome (chrome)
[        ] [3]: Edge (edge)
[   +3 ms] Please choose one (To quit, press "q/Q")
[        ] :
[+23630 ms] 2
[  +14 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[  +25 ms] Found plugin android_intent at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-2.0.0\
[  +37 ms] Found plugin flutter_inappwebview at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\
[   +8 ms] Found plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.2\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin fluttertoast at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-8.0.7\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin geolocator at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.1.14\
[   +7 ms] Found plugin google_map_location_picker at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_map_location_picker-4.1.7\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.6\
[  +11 ms] Found plugin location at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-2.5.4\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin package_info at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\package_info-2.0.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.2\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-2.0.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin path_provider_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_windows-2.0.1\      
[   +7 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-2.0.6\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_web-2.0.0\    
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_windows-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin sqflite at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-2.0.0+3\
[  +11 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-6.0.4\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_linux-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_windows-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin video_player at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player-2.1.4\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin video_player_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player_web-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin wakelock at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock-0.5.2\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin wakelock_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock_macos-0.1.0+1\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin wakelock_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock_web-0.2.0+1\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin webview_flutter at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.8\
[ +149 ms] Found plugin android_intent at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-2.0.0\
[  +15 ms] Found plugin flutter_inappwebview at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.2\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin fluttertoast at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-8.0.7\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin geolocator at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.1.14\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin google_map_location_picker at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_map_location_picker-4.1.7\
[        ] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.6\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin location at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-2.5.4\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin package_info at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\package_info-2.0.0\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.2\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin path_provider_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin path_provider_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin path_provider_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_windows-2.0.1\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-2.0.6\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_web-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_windows-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin sqflite at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-2.0.0+3\
[   +6 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-6.0.4\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_linux-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_windows-2.0.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin video_player at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player-2.1.4\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin video_player_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player_web-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin wakelock at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock-0.5.2\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin wakelock_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock_macos-0.1.0+1\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin wakelock_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock_web-0.2.0+1\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin webview_flutter at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.8\
[  +14 ms] Generating C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\applications\acl_app\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[ +124 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
[ +113 ms] Updating assets
[ +150 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for more information see #56466.
[   +7 ms] Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
[   +9 ms] Found plugin android_intent at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-2.0.0\
[  +11 ms] Found plugin flutter_inappwebview at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.2\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin fluttertoast at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-8.0.7\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin geolocator at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.1.14\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin google_map_location_picker at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_map_location_picker-4.1.7\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.6\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin location at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-2.5.4\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin package_info at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\package_info-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.2\
[        ] Found plugin path_provider_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin path_provider_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin path_provider_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_windows-2.0.1\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-2.0.6\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_web-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_windows-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin sqflite at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-2.0.0+3\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-6.0.4\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_linux-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_windows-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin video_player at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player-2.1.4\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin video_player_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player_web-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin wakelock at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock-0.5.2\
[        ] Found plugin wakelock_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock_macos-0.1.0+1\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin wakelock_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock_web-0.2.0+1\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin webview_flutter at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.8\
[   +8 ms] Found plugin android_intent at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-2.0.0\
[  +10 ms] Found plugin flutter_inappwebview at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.2\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin fluttertoast at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-8.0.7\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin geolocator at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.1.14\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin google_map_location_picker at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_map_location_picker-4.1.7\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.6\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin location at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-2.5.4\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin package_info at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\package_info-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.2\
[        ] Found plugin path_provider_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin path_provider_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin path_provider_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_windows-2.0.1\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-2.0.6\
[        ] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_web-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_windows-2.0.0\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin sqflite at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-2.0.0+3\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-6.0.4\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_linux at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_linux-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin url_launcher_windows at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_windows-2.0.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin video_player at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player-2.1.4\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin video_player_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player_web-2.0.0\
[        ] Found plugin wakelock at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock-0.5.2\
[        ] Found plugin wakelock_macos at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock_macos-0.1.0+1\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin wakelock_web at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wakelock_web-0.2.0+1\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin webview_flutter at C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.8\
[ +156 ms] <- reset
[   +7 ms] C:\dev\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\dev\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\dev\flutter\bin\cache\flutter_web_sdk/ --incremental --target=dartdevc --debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true
--output-dill C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.f865597f\flutter_tool.c8f04285\app.dill --libraries-spec
file:///C:/dev/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/libraries.json --packages C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\applications\acl_app\.dart_tool\package_config.json
-Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-root
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.f865597f\flutter_tools.7f9b301a --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-app --initialize-from-dill
build\c7922d95bf4a2462b75c84a97c312edb.cache.dill.track.dill --platform file:///C:/dev/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/kernel/flutter_ddc_sdk.dill --no-sound-null-safety   
[  +77 ms] <- compile org-dartlang-app:/web_entrypoint.dart
[+31633 ms] Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome... (completed in 32.0s)
[   +1 ms] Synced 62.2MB.
[   +1 ms] <- accept
[        ] Caching compiled dill
[+1217 ms] [CHROME]:
[   +1 ms] [CHROME]:DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65173/devtools/browser/a02b253f-d3cb-4f81-84d3-ed3c0b9bfe14
[+4044 ms] DwdsInjector: Received request for entrypoint at http://localhost:56392/main_module.bootstrap.js
[   +5 ms] MetadataProvider: Loading debug metadata...
[  +27 ms] MetadataProvider: Loaded debug metadata (no sound null safety)
[  +15 ms] DwdsInjector: Injected debugging metadata for entrypoint at http://localhost:56392/main_module.bootstrap.js
[+15336 ms] ChromeProxyService: Initializing expression compiler for main_module.bootstrap.js with sound null safety: false
[ +117 ms] DevHandler: Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51056/EQ4I8a1ypeE=/ws

[  +24 ms] This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:51056/EQ4I8a1ypeE=/ws
[   +9 ms] Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51056/EQ4I8a1ypeE=/ws
[        ] Running with unsound null safety
[        ] For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
[   +3 ms]   To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".
[        ] For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".
[   +1 ms] An Observatory debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:51056/EQ4I8a1ypeE=
[+1533 ms] Activating Dart DevTools...
[+7623 ms] Log [base_url: https://soqo.co.ke/datadata/public/api/] | (897:28   get current)
[  +13 ms] Log [api_base_url: https://soqo.co.ke/africanapp/] | (897:28   get current)
[ +206 ms] Log [{app_name: , default_tax: null, default_currency: null, default_currency_decimal_digits: 2, currency_right: false, enable_paypal: true, enable_stripe: true,
                    enable_razorpay: true, mobile_language: en}] | (897:28       get current)
```

........

Comment: I was able to solve this one... if anyone requires my solution ill post it. Thanks.

Comment: please post the solution